# AngularJS Resolve some factory promises for all routes

Tags: angularjs, promise, factory, ng-storage

I have problem with my app. I have a factory, that calls `prepareStorage` to save all static vars from my `restApi` to the browser storage (using `ngStorage`). It seems like this:

```
angular.module('panelApp')
       .factory('prepareStorage', ['$localStorage', '$sessionStorage', 'apiService',

  function($localStorage, $sessionStorage, apiService) {
    var promise = {};
    var load = function() {
    apiService.call('head', 'staticTypes.json', [], function(response, status, head) {

    if(angular.isUndefined($localStorage.staticTypes) || $localStorage.staticTypes.updatedAt < new Date(head()['last-modified'])){
       delete $localStorage.staticTypes;
       promise = apiService.call('get', 'statictypes.json', [], function (response) {
          $localStorage.staticTypes = response;
       }, function (errorObj) {
          console.log(errorObj.error.message);
       });
     }
  });


  return promise;

  return {
           load: load()
         };
}]);
```

Then I have declared a second factory `constantsService`, that gives me the storage vars:

```
angular.module('panelApp')
    .factory('constantsService', ['$localStorage', '$q', 'prepareStorage', '$timeout',

  function($localStorage, $q, prepareStorage, $timeout) {
    var output = {};
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $timeout(function() {
      deferred.resolve(prepareStorage.load, function() {
          output = {
              status: $localStorage.staticTypes.status
          };
      });
    }, 1000);

     return output;

}]);
```

And now comes my trouble in this case.

> I can't get this storage vars inside my controller without a
>   re-refresh. That means, that after the first site refresh, the
>   controller doesn't find the `$localStorage.staticTypes.status` object,
>   it does only if I refresh a second time.

**I'm looking for a clean solution avoiding `$timeout` service usage.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this different pattern?

**prepareStorage**

```
angular.module('panelApp')
       .factory('prepareStorage', prepareStorage);

prepareStorage.$inject = [ '$localStorage', '$sessionStorage', 'apiService' ];

  function prepareStorage ($localStorage, $sessionStorage, apiService) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.load = function() {
       return new Promise( function(resolve, reject){
          apiService.call('head', 'staticTypes.json', [], function(response, status, head) {
           if(angular.isUndefined($localStorage.staticTypes) || $localStorage.staticTypes.updatedAt < new Date(head()['last-modified'])){
            delete $localStorage.staticTypes;
            apiService.call('get', 'statictypes.json').then( function (response, error) {
              if(response){
                $localStorage.staticTypes = response;
                return resolve(response);
              }
              return reject(error);
            });
           }
          });
       });
    }

  return {
           load: load
         };
});
```

And **constantsService**

```
angular.module('panelApp')
    .factory('constantsService', constantsService);

    constantsService.$inject = [ '$localStorage', '$q', 'prepareStorage', '$timeout' ];

  function constantsService($localStorage, $q, prepareStorage, $timeout) {

  var vm = this;

  vm.getStorage = function(){
     prepareStorage.load().then( function( response){
      return response;
    });
  }


     return : {
                getStorage : getStorage
     }

}]);
```

And I would refactor **apiService** to be a `Promise` itself like

```
. . .

//E.g. Method = get, document = statictypes.json
vm.call = function(method, document){
   return new Promise( function (resolve, reject){
      ... do something
      if(everyThingIsOk){
        return resolve(response);
      }

      return reject(error);
   });
}
```

I can't guarantee this is right 100% but it should work if you understand how to use it. You just wait for a promise to return before doing something. I think you should structure your `apiService` like I did, so you can use `.then()` on them too.

Hope It helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I tried it - firstly resolve the fex errors (eg. getStorage -> vm.getStorage) and finally the returned object getStorage is undefined after call inside controller:
constantsService.getStorage()
but the response is also correct

Comment: Hi can you explain better? I did not understand what you mean with *firstly resolve the fex errors (eg. getStorage -> vm.getStorage) and finally the returned object getStorage is undefined after call inside controller: constantsService.getStorage() but the response is also correct*

Comment: PS: the apiService method "call" has the following initialisation:
`code`call: function (method, endpoint, payload, success, error, url) { }

Comment: Yes, sorry I had typo in my last comment fex -> first
You have two errors in your script-code:
1. return { load: vm:load
2. return { getStorage: vm:getStorage }

Comment: Edited my answer.